# Generating different percentages of MAR data in R

Tags: r, regression, missing-data

The following​ two R functions are from the book "Flexible Imputation of Missing Data" (page no. 59 and 63). The first one generates missing completely at random(MCAR) data and the second on generates missing at random(MAR) data. Both functions give approximately 50% missing values.  ​

In MCAR function, we can generate different percentages of missing data by changing the p value. But in MAR function, ​I don't understand ​which parameter should we change to generate different percentages of missing data like 10% or 30%?

## MCAR

```
makemissing <- function(data, p=0.5){
  rx <- rbinom(nrow(data), 1, p)
  data[rx==0,"y"] <- NA
  return(data)
}
```

## MAR

```
logistic <- function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))
set.seed(32881)
n <- 10000
y <- mvrnorm(n=n,mu=c(5,5),Sigma=matrix(c(1,0.6,0.6,1),nrow=2))
p2.marright <- 1 - logistic(-5 + y[,1])
r2.marright <- rbinom(n, 1, p2.marright)
yobs <- y
yobs[r2.marright==0, 2] <- NA
```

Comment: For an informative coverage of missing data topics see **Statistical Analysis with Missing Data 2nd Edition by Roderick J.A. Little and Donald B. Rubin (2002) Wiley**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of an observation being missing is 50% for every case for the MCAR function because, by definition, the missingness is random. For the MAR version, the probability of an observation being missing is different for each observation, since it depends on the values of `y[,1]`. In your code, the probability of missingness on `y[,2]` is saved in the variable `p2.marright`. You can perhaps see this more easily by lining up all of the values in a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(y1 = y[,1], y2_ori = y[,2], y2_mis = yobs[,2], p2.marright = p2.marright, r2.marright)
head(df)
        y1   y2_ori   y2_mis p2.marright r2.marright
1 2.086475 3.432803 3.432803   0.9485110           1
2 3.784675 5.005584 5.005584   0.7712399           1
3 4.818409 5.356688       NA   0.5452733           0
4 2.937422 3.898014 3.898014   0.8872124           1
5 6.422158 5.032659 5.032659   0.1943236           1
6 4.115106 5.083162 5.083162   0.7078354           1
```

You can see that whether or not an observation will be NA on `y2` is encoded in `r2.marright`, which is a probabilistic binary version of `p2.marright` --- for higher values of `p2.marright`, `r2.marright` is more likely to 1. To change the overall rate of missingness, you can change the calculation of `p2.marright` to bias it higher or lower.

You can manipulate `p2.marright` by changing the constant in the logistic transformation (-5 in the example). If you increase it (make it less negative, e.g. -4) then `p2.marright` will decrease, resulting in more missing values on y2. If you decrease it (make it more negative, e.g. -6) then you'll end up with fewer missing values on y2. (The reason -5 is resulting in 50% missingness is because 5 is the mean of the variable being transformed, `y1`.) This works, but the mechanism is rather opaque, and it might be difficult for you to control it easily. For example, it's not obvious what you should set the constant to be if you want 20% missingness on `y2`.

Comment: @Shoheb If this solves your problem, you can accept it as an answer.